# how to echo without line breaks in php?

Tags: php, html, newline, echo

How do i echo all array elements in a single line whitout line breaks on every itteration though the array?
This is the code i was able to come up with but it prints every element on a new line.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<h3> Some text'. $row['user_name'] . '</h3>';
}
```

Comment: There is not a single line-break involved in the code you've shared. Additionally as you probably dislike to have the output as headlines, why are you still wrapping the outputs into `<h3>` tags?

Comment: h3 adds a new line after it, change the tag or change it with css.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`h3` is a block element. You can make it display in line by not using `h3` (use `span` maybe) or styling it to be inline:

CSS:

```
h3 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `<h3>`, like other `<hx>` tags are block level elements, and so will render on their own line.  You either use an inline element, like `<span>` or set the display property of the `<h3>` tag to *display: inline* in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
echo '<h3>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['user_name'];
}
echo '</h3>';
```

Comment: the issue is the tag itself.

Comment: @thescientist it's still a block element but by echoing all of the items inside one tag, they will be inline as OP wants.

Comment: interesting approach, but the OP might have a good reason for each row to be represented as its own unique DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS You can float those elements.

```
h3 {
    float: left;
}
```

With PHP You can output one element containing all those rows:

```
echo '<h3>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['user_name'];
}
echo '</h3>';
```

Comment: I would advise against float in this case as it may (probably will) lead to unnecessary layout issues. `display: inline` is definitely the best solution as it directly addresses the issue of making a block element inline.